# How to get the <a> element currently selected using the tab key?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I have a webpage which has many links (mostly `mailto` but I don't think that's relevant), where accessibility is a priority. Due to the formatting, when the tab key is used to move around the page, the currently selected link is often off the bottom of the screen, because only the very top of the containing card is visible: the built-in autoscroll of the browser doesn't scroll far enough. How can I get the currently "selected" (highlighted with the tab key) element so I can control the scrolling manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the currently focused element of the page you can use

```
document.activeElement
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.activeElement.id`

`document.activeElement` gives a reference to the current active element. You can use this just like what an element query returns (`document.querySelector()`)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the currently "selected" (highlighted with the tab key) element so I can control the scrolling manually?

If you may know which element is currently focused with the <kbd>tab</kbd> key (using `document.activeElement`), you also have to take care of the automatic scrolling performed when using a screenreader or any other assistive technologies (eye tracking device, for instance).

The fact that your scrolling relies on javascript detection of standard keyboard/mouse events or standard element activation might be problematic when using assistive technologies.

Relying on the built-in autoscroll, while not your solution, is however the best solution.